# How to change length of generated passwords in Firefox

Tags: firefox, configuration, passwords

Firefox offers to generate passwords on websites during account creation with a length of 16 symbols consisting of upper- and lower-case letters and numbers.
Is there a way to change/configure this length?

Comment: doesn't look like it. 
But length should be auto detected https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634783 ; few things are on the roadmap it seems: https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/discussions/password-generation-in-firefox/m-p/4217/highlight/true#M1884